# Angular lib - expose common scss

Tags: angular, sass, lib

I am trying to create a bundle of my common styles defined in my angular library.
I want to use mixins, functions, variables, etc. from my lib in my future projects.

Usually in this situation I used to scss-bundle tool => https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle , but as I know this solution is deprecated for sass '@use' '@forward' and when I am trying to run scss-bundle I get an unknown import error, because in my index.scss I use the '@forward' keyword.

Is there any other solution, how to bundling scss files from angular lib and move it to dist directly? 
I know, I can do it by webpack, parcel, etc., but I do not want to attach it to my lib dependencies. 
Is there any more configurable approach, something directly from angular, or some simple npm tool like scss-bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official documentation of ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md) you can now specify the directory and / or files you would like to copy into the bundle.

```js
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-component-library",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  },
  "assets": [
    "./my-dir"
  ]
}
```

You can then reference this dir as: `@import ~my-library/my-dir`.
Keep in mind that, given the above config, `my-dir` needs to be at the root of the library. Another thing to mention is that `ng-packagr` preserves the tree structure. For example, if you have the following config:

```
"assets": [
 "./dir1/dir2/my-dir"
]
```

then after you build your library, you would need to reference my-dir like so:
`@import ~my-library/dir1/dir2/my-dir`.